# Empty stacks from torch profiler

Tags: python, pytorch, profiling

### Details of the problem

Hello, I am trying to reproduce the profiler example of the [official Pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html#visualizing-data-as-a-flamegraph). I want to export stacks of a forward pass of a model.

**Although, the stacks files are created and they are empty.**

```py
import torch
from torch import profiler
from torchvision.models import resnet18

model = resnet18().cuda()
inputs = torch.rand(5, 3, 224, 224).cuda()


with profiler.profile(
    activities=[profiler.ProfilerActivity.CPU,
                profiler.ProfilerActivity.CUDA],
    with_stack=True,
)as p:
    model(inputs)

p.export_stacks(
    f"/tmp/profiler/stacks_cpu.txt", "self_cpu_time_total")
p.export_stacks(
    f"/tmp/profiler/stacks_cuda.txt", "self_cuda_time_total")
```

###### Environment information

- Running on Docker image pytorch/pytorch:2.0.0-cuda11.7-cudnn8-runtime
- torch: 2.0.0
- torchvision: 0.15.0
- Python: 3.10.9

**Note:** I reproduced it on the bare docker image.

### What I tried

The very weird thing is that when I print the table from my script, I can see the trace. I give the exact snippet of code I use for that, I just put them right after the snippet of code above.

```py
print(p.key_averages(group_by_stack_n=5).table(
    sort_by="self_cuda_time_total", row_limit=2))
```

**Update**: The printing option is also not working. It prints the table but not the stacks. With debug I can see the function `_build_table` in module `torch.autograd.profiler_util`. On [Line 794](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/a204f7f51810f00acd4fd4737e831f0ca9ff0e9c/torch/autograd/profiler_util.py#L794), the `stacks` variable is an empty list. (`_build_table` is called on `table` method in code snippet above).
Also, in `key_averages` method of the class `EventList` - which is called in `key_averages` of `profiler` class (used in the code snipped) - each event has an empty `stacks` attribute on [line 298](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/a204f7f51810f00acd4fd4737e831f0ca9ff0e9c/torch/autograd/profiler_util.py#L298) .
So question is, why the stack is not filled in those events? I will investigate furthermore.

Answer (score 5):

On the pytorch repo there is an [issue #100253](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/100253) that answers the final question of my post. I let you read the issue for more details.

In brief, there was an error on torch version 2.0.0 about the profiler. Their example is simpler: they try to profile an addition of 2 tensors. Their investigation is the same as mine, they end up with the same conclusion: the stacks is not filled by the profiler because the events has an empty `stacks` attribute. Their investigation is more located because they compared two version of torch (1.13.0 VS 2.0.0) and they find the number of events are not the same. The profiler's tracing is done in C++, so I cannot investigate further.

The current fix is to go back to torch 1.13.0 waiting the fix.

Thanks to the person who brought this issue on torch repo and thanks to the maintainers of torch!

Comment: There's a workaround in the comments: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/100253#issuecomment-1579804477